# How to update ComboBox on form1 after saving the record on another form at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have one form, "form1", which contains a template ComboBox and a create template-button. When I click the create template-button, a new form opens for saving a new template record. The record is saved successsfuly on the second form but when it closes,  the ComboBox was not updated at runtime with the template name which was saved in database. So how to refresh or reload the ComboBox at runtime?

Comment: can you update the question with how you set data source to ComboBox ?

Answer (score 2):

you can load the ComboBox again on closing event of child form as below

```
private void LoadChildForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChildForm form = new ChildForm();
    form.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(ChildFormClosed);
    form.Show();
}

void ChildFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // Load data and bind to ComboBox 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass parent form(form 1) to form 2, and make public method in form 1 which update your combo box, and call that method on close form 2.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into databinding.
[Databinding MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)

This way you can keep a list of templates and let your UI controls be updated through events send by the list itself when things change!  This technique is much easier to maintain as your UI will grow and grow!